# Lotus Notes: Connection Error [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: odbc, lotus-notes, windows-shell, lotus, lotusscript

In one of the Lotus Notes application which requires connection with external SQL DB, we have one user who is getting error message prompt because ODBC driver is not able to connect. 
I did following checks:
1. User had permissions to EDIT registry HKLM-Software-ODBC
2. User is able to access the db server (i pinged server IP from user's machine)
3. Made sure that user had admin acces to computer.

This is how code works. The code first runs a VBscript which sets registry variables, then uses LotusScript with NSLXODBC to connect to the DB (ConnectTo method).

The only difference I found between users not having issue and those reporting issue is that USER REPORTING ISSUE had new laptop and it had windows 7 OS.

Lotus Notes Version: 6.5

Comment: Notes 6.5 on Windows 7? Are they also using Microsoft Office 2003? Upgrade!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely in the ODBC setup then.  The registry changes are supposed to set up the ODBC connection but I'd bet the same code doesn't work for Windows 7.  Try manually creating the ODBC connection from that user's laptop.

Comment: that is my approach ... But i confirmed values in registry changed.. That is what makes my brain swirl around.. Anyways i will try configuring it manually.